# importing csv file occur data type mismatch in criteria expression to access

Tags: c#, ms-access, csv

I am importing csv file from C# windows to access database.
 When I import CSV, then occur data type mismatch in criteria expression.
 Thanks for answering.

Here is my CSV file:

```
2,Each Product less 2 dollars,minus,0,2,2014/7/3,2014/7/31,0
```

Here is my table:

```
DiscountID(Int),Dis_Description(Text),Dis_Type(Text),Dis_Quantity(Int)
Dis_Value(Int),Start_Date(DateTime),EndTime(DateTime),Dis_Price(Int)
```

Here is Code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE " + database + " SET  [Dis_Description] = '" + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim() + "'," + "[Dis_Type] = '" + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim() + "'," + "[Dis_Quantity] = '" + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim() + "'," + "[Dis_Value] = '" + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString().Trim() + "'," + "[Start_Date] = '" + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString().Trim() + "'," + "[Expiry_Date] = '" + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString().Trim() + "'," + "[Dis_Price] = '" + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString().Trim()+ "' WHERE DiscountID = " + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim() + "'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

UPDATE CODE: It also occur data type mismatch in criteria expression to access.

```
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Discounts SET [Dis_Description]=?,[Dis_Type]=?,[Dis_Quantity]=?,[Dis_Value]=?,[Start_Date]=?,[Expiry_Date]=?,[Dis_Value]=? WHERE [DiscountID] = ?;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString().Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is your problem:

```
WHERE DiscountID = " + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim() + "'";
```

It maybe should read:

```
WHERE DiscountID = '" + dtCSV.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim() + "'";
```

Looks like a **single quote** got left out.

Also, why all the joins between field names?  i.e.

```
+ "'," + "[Dis_Quantity] = '" +
```

can be

```
+ "', [Dis_Quantity] = '" +
```

etc...

Comment: Maybe parameters to avoid all problems, such as a contained single quote?

Comment: I tried to left out the single quote. It also occur data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: @Remou Are you mean cmd.Parameters.Add? I also tried.

Comment: @user3762969 Yes, I do mean .CreateParameter, if it is not working for you, post your code ad any error messages. The current string is unsafe.

Comment: Furthermore, you should be able to simply run this in one query. However, a staging table might not be a bad idea.

Comment: @Remou I updated the code and it also occur data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: You can't use a question mark for every variable name.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Yes, you can.

Comment: @Remou I tried to run SQL update statement immediately. UPDATE Discounts SET [Dis_Description]='XXXX',.....WHERE DiscountID = 2;I can update it,but Import csv file occur the problems.